# Office Add-In - Handle 'This add-in is not responding' warning message

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

I found a hacky solution to the problem I had in this question: [JSPDF - Use lots and lots of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698732/jspdf-use-lots-and-lots-of-images). I didn't upload the answer because it's not really an answer because of the problem below.

I was able to use JSPDF with as many pages as I want (quite literally... I ran a test with 20,000 and roughly 100k images and it worked. Tooks it's sweet time and a sweet spot on my HD, but it worked)

The problem now is that I get a warning that says 'This add-in is not responding.' And it gives a 'refresh' button for the add-in.

Is there a way to tell Office 'Hey, i"m actually responding?' This happens every time I try setTimeout and setInterval.

**Clarification:**

The yellow warning message gives the option to restart and doesn't manually restart for you like the red warning message does. I don't think it looks great if every time a PDF is made it says 'this add-in is not responding' when in fact it is.

Answer (score 0):

The warning happens when the main thread hasn't been responsive in a while, thus blocking the UI. Have you tried running this on a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker)? This would leave the main thread available while your long running operations happen.

Let me know how this works out for you

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Thanks for the response. Question, though. I see that workers require their own .js file in order to run. I have 4 PDFs to make in the add-in; Is there an easier way to do it than making 4 separate files?

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from re-using the same JS file in 4 different web-worker.